# Userform throwing error when checkbox = true in If Then Else Statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, userform

Throwing an error for the following code. The error code says, "Compile error: Expected: Then or Go to"

Here's the code is having issues with.

```
Private Sub Userform.Initialize()
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P1").Value = "Y"
            Then
            CheckBox1.Value = True
            Else
            CheckBox1.Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Any insight on how to correct this error? I feel like the code is solid.

Comment: Then is expected to be on the same line as the If statement.  If you want to put it on the next line, you need a line continuation character (_) at the end of the line with the If statement

Comment: Thank you! Of course now I feel kind of dumb. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and I feel kind of dumb. I was missing the underscore at the end of the initial IF statement.

The code now reads as follows:

```
Private Sub Userform.Initialize()
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P1").Value = "Y" _
        Then
        CheckBox1.Value = True
        Else
        CheckBox1.Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```